# Typings: Array<Promise<T>> to Promise<Array<T>>

Tags: typescript

I've written a helper method and added it to Array.prototype to wrap an array of promises in `Promise.all`.

```
Array.prototype.awaitPromises = function() {
  return Promise.all(this);
}
```

Now I'm trying to get TypeScript typings to work, but I don't see a way to "unpack" the Array type into a Promise-wrapped value:

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    awaitPromises<U>(): Promise<Array<U>>
  }
}
```

Ideally I'd like `Array<Promise<T>>` -> `Promise<Array<T>>` and to get rid of needing to specify `<U>`. Is this possible, or am I stuck with what I've got?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

My bad, you can simply do it like this:

```
interface PromiseArray<T> extends Array<T | Promise<T>> {
    awaitPromises(): Promise<Array<T>>;
}
```

**But** I still think that it's better design to have a class who extends `Array` and only that has the `awaitPromises` method, after all that's what object oriented is all about.
This is what I had in mind in my original answer:

### Original

The problem is that you don't always have just promises in the array, you can put values there as well not just promises.

More than that, by adding this method to the `Array`, you basically say "all arrays may contain promises" or "all arrays may be used as a parameter to `Promise.all`".

What's wrong with subclassing `Array`?

```
class PromiseArray<T> extends Array<T | Promise<T>> {
    awaitPromises(): Promise<Array<T>> {
        return Promise.all(this);
    }
}
```

The key here (I think) is the `Array<T | Promise<T>>` part, which you can't really do if you just extend the default `Array<T>` interface globally.
And, you have a clear distinction of which arrays can await on promises, which I think is a better design.

You can also add a function to the `Array` prototype to return `this` as a `PromiseArray`:

```
interface Array<T> {
    toPromiseArray(): PromiseArray<T>;
}

Array.prototype.toPromiseArray = function() {
    let arr = new PromiseArray<any>();
    this.forEach(item => arr.push(item));
    return arr;
}
```